# Set limit on characters read from Reader

Tags: java, file

I am trying to implement a multi-threaded file reader, where in each thread reads a chunk of bytes from the same file. 
I initialize the `Reader` in each thread and `skip` accordingly, but my `Reader` is used by another library,(`CsvMapReader`) and I would like a thread to read only `chunk` bytes. How do I ensure that the `Reader` object that I pass to `CsvMapReader` is able to read only `chunk` bytes and not till EOF.

Sample:

```
Thread reader = new Thread(() -> {
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader("large_file");
  br.skip(chunkSize);
  CsvMapReader leftFileReader = new CsvMapReader(br, filePreference);
  while (csvMapReader.read() != null) { /* This loop should only iterate until chunksize bytes are processed, and no more */
    // do something
  }
})
reader.start();
```

Assume, I have multiple thread, each one skip some multiple of `chunkSize`. Basically I would like to only loop until `chunkSize` bytes have been processed.

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to chunk out a number of rows (the unit your csv reader reads), instead of a number of bytes?

Comment: You can make your own `Reader` class that wraps your `BufferedReader` and gives EOF after so many bytes have been read.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like the code below. You can have a counter variable to count the characters read and read only till chunkSize is reached. Also, I assume your chunkSize is 
 character size since you are using a Reader and not inputStream.

```
    Thread reader = new Thread(() -> {
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader("large_file");
         br.skip(chunkSize);
          CsvMapReader leftFileReader =
                 new CsvMapReader(br, filePreference);
            int chunkSizeCounter=0;
            while (csvMapReader.read() != null && 
                        chunkSizeCounter< chunkSize ) {
                         // do something
                      chunkSizeCounter++;
             }
          })
         reader.start();
```

You can also read specific lines per thread instead of reading  specific bytes or characters per thread. When you read lines, you make lesser checks for size and it may be a bit faster

Comment: Got the solution to this. I had to use `InputStream` instead, along with your suggestion to count the read bytes.

Comment: @Fayaz    That is nice to hear. You can post your solution if you like

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve it by creating new `InputStream` per thread, as creating just `BufferedReader` was affecting all the threads since they share the same filepointer.

```
Thread reader = new Thread(() -> {
  InputStream is = new InputStream("large_file")
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
  is.skip(chunkSize);
  CsvMapReader leftFileReader = new CsvMapReader(br, filePreference);
  while (csvMapReader.read() != null) { /* This loop should only iterate until chunksize bytes are processed, and no more */
    // do something
  }
})
reader.start();
```